# Render is running before async method ends. How can i pass props to component from my async method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I neet to pass data from firestore into my components. But request is async so i stuck on problem when my render method runs before i get data from my request. So when the render runs the pops value is Null because state is not defined yet. Also component for some reason renders twice.
Is there any better way to handle async stuff?

Already tried po put request to firestore in higher place (index.js) and pass data down to app.
Tried to make request inside render method.
Tried to put request inside async function and call it in constructor to set state there. Same thing as calling async method.

```
class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.giveUsername = this.giveUsername.bind(this);

    const userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.email;
    this.giveUsername(userId);
}

async giveUsername(userId){
    let username;
    await firebase.firestore().collection('users').where('email', '==', userId).get().then((snapshot) =>{
        snapshot.docs.forEach(doc =>{
            console.log(`doc.data().username - ${doc.data().username}`);
            username = doc.data().username;
        });
    });
    this.setState( {
        userId : userId,
        username : username
    });
 }

render() {
    return (
      <div className='App'>
        <Header username={this.state.username}/>
        <NewTask userId={this.state.userId}/>
        <TaskList userId={this.state.userId}/>
      </div>
    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Render will run before you get your data, that’s totally normal and correct. Check if the data is `null` and render a loading message or nothing (`return null`)

Answer (score 0):

you should initialize the `state` in the constructor so your component renders properly even without data, and add a `loading` key to know when the data are ready, and it would be useful to show a pinner

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    state = {
      userId : 0,
      username : '',
      loading: true
    }
}
```

set the `loading` to `false` when data are are ready :

```
async giveUsername(userId){
    ...
    this.setState( {
        userId : userId,
        username : username,
        loading: false
    });
 }
```

Render :

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className='App'>
        {this.state.loading 
         ? <span>Loading ... </span> 
         : (
             <Header username={this.state.username}/>
             <NewTask userId={this.state.userId}/>
             <TaskList userId={this.state.userId}/>
           )
        }
      </div>
    );
}
```

and the reason why the component is rendering twince is because the `state` is changing and that's normal.

Answer (score 0):

The general thing to understand when making requests is that, it's expected that there won't be any data at the start of your component and there is nothing you can do about that.

Best practices is to let the user know that the data is loading.

```
constructor(){
  this.state = {username: null, userId: null, loaded: false};
}
render() {
    return (
      <div className='App'>
        {
           !this.state.loaded ? <p>Loading...</p> : 

              <Header username={this.state.username}/>
              <NewTask userId={this.state.userId}/>
              <TaskList userId={this.state.userId}/>
        }
      </div>
    );
}
```

Do not do fetch requests in your controller ! Use `componentDidMount`

```
componentDidMount(){
    const userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.email;
    this.giveUsername(userId);
}
```

Then finally in `giveUsername`

```
async giveUsername(userId){
    let username;
    await firebase.firestore().collection('users').where('email', '==', userId).get().then((snapshot) =>{
        snapshot.docs.forEach(doc =>{
            console.log(`doc.data().username - ${doc.data().username}`);
            username = doc.data().username;
        });
    });
    this.setState( {
        userId : userId,
        username : username,
        loaded: true
    });
 }
```